# Changing chart location in excel produce an access violation

Tags: delphi, excel-2010

Using Delphi, I create an excel sheet with some data values, then I create a chart:

```
WChart := ((ExcelApplication1.Workbooks[1].ActiveSheet) as _Worksheet).Shapes.AddChart(xl3DPie,
                                 EmptyParam, EmptyParam,
                                 EmptyParam, EmptyParam).Chart;
```

The chart is correctly created on the sheet.
Now I want to move it to a new sheet like this:

```
WChart.Location(xlLocationAsNewSheet, EmptyParam);
```

This results in an access violation.

I Googled a lot and found no example which makes use of Delphi. All other languages (Like VBA) are doing something equivalent to my code.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the assembly code for the line triggering the AV:

```
WChart.Location(xlLocationAsNewSheet, EmptyParam);
   lea eax,[ebp-$0000019c]
   call @IntfClear
   push eax
   lea eax,[ebp-$000001ac]
   call EmptyParam
   push dword ptr [ebp-$000001a0]
   push dword ptr [ebp-$000001a4]
   push dword ptr [ebp-$000001a8]
   push dword ptr [ebp-$000001ac]
   push $01
   mov eax,[ebp-$14]                 // [ebp-$14] is WChart value
   push eax
   mov eax,[eax]
   call dword ptr [eax+$00000198]    // Supposed to call Location()
   call @CheckAutoResult
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the access violation? (What's the specific message, including memory addresses involved?) Also, where is the code that tries to move the chart in relation to the code that creates it? Is

Comment: Have you tried giving the new sheet a name (instead of EmptyParam)?

Comment: Access violation is "exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00080004: read of address 0x00080004'. The two lines I mentioned are just one after the other. Using a sheet name doesn't change anything.

Comment: Do you have the ability to try the same thing using VB or C# just to see if this is a bug in Office 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out the specific problem you're having (I get a different AV, but it's still an AV). However, here's a workaround if you're interested.

```
var
  Book: _Workbook;
  LCID: Integer;
  Chart: _Chart;
begin
  LCID := GetUserDefaultLCID;

  Book := ExcelApplication1.ActiveWorkbook;
  Chart := Book.Charts.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, 
                           EmptyParam, EmptyParam, LCID) as _Chart;

  // Tested, and the second param below can be EmptyParam to leave
  // the new sheet name as "Chart1".
  Chart.Location(xlLocationAsNewSheet, 'ChartSheet');
end;
```